# Why clang++ fails to compile code proposed by clang-tidy

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++, clang-tidy

I have a very simple code with reverse-iteration loop:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<unsigned>();
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    for (auto r = v.rbegin(); r != v.rend(); ++r)
    {
        std::cout << *r;
    }
}
```

clang-tidy proposes to change the loop using `ranges`:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<unsigned>();
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    for (unsigned int & r : std::ranges::reverse_view(v))
    {
        std::cout << r;
    }
}
```

clang++ compiles the first version cleanly, but [fails to compile the transformed version](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:16),source:%27%23include+%3Cranges%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+v+%3D+std::vector%3Cunsigned%3E()%3B%0A++++v.push_back(1)%3B%0A++++v.push_back(2)%3B%0A++++v.push_back(3)%3B%0A%0A++++for+(unsigned+int+%26+r+:+std::ranges::reverse_view(v))%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+r%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1400,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4). g++ accepts both versions.

For both compilers I use the following args: `-std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

I am using:

- clang++ `Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1`
- clang-tidy `Ubuntu LLVM version 14.0.0`
- g++ `g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0`

**What is the root cause of this compilation failure?** The change proposed by clang-tidy seems legit. Is the problem due to lacking C++20 support in clang++ (the compiler or shipped standard library)?

The original file, clang-tidy config, and transformed file are available in [this repository](https://github.com/kkarbowiak/clang-tidy-fail).

Comment: It seems `clang-tidy-14` suggests a change that `clang-14` can't handle. :-) `clang-16` compiles it clean too.

Comment: This is just a long-standing issue that clang cannot compile libstdc++ ranges because of issues in the implementation of concepts in clang. Newer clang finally does compile it, or you can use libc++ (but this requires also providing `-fexperimental-library` to use ranges).